# Exception: Foreign Key Constraint may cause multiple cycles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I am new to `ASP .NET`. I am trying to do simple CRUD using the following Model. There are three `ChartOfAccountId`s in `Paper` class, so there are three Parent-Child relations. One of these relations `ChartOfAccountIdInventory` is causing the following Exception:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint FK_dbo.Papers_dbo.ChartOfAccounts_ChartOfAccountIdInventory' on table 'Papers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint.
```

**ChartOfAccount Class:**

```
public partial class ChartOfAccount
{
    public ChartOfAccount()
    {
        this.PapersSale = new HashSet<Paper>();
        this.PapersCostOfSale = new HashSet<Paper>();
        this.PapersInventory = new HashSet<Paper>();
    }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Paper> PapersSale { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Paper> PapersCostOfSale { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Paper> PapersInventory { get; set; }
}
```

**Paper Class:**

```
    public class Paper
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Chart Of Account For Sale")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Chart Of Account is required")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ChartOfAccountIdSale { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Chart Of Account For Inventory")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Chart Of Account is required")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ChartOfAccountIdInventory { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Chart Of Account For Cost Of Sale")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Chart Of Account is required")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ChartOfAccountIdCostOfSale { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ChartOfAccountIdSale")]
        public virtual ChartOfAccount ChartOfAccountSale { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ChartOfAccountIdInventory")]
        public virtual ChartOfAccount ChartOfAccountInventory { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ChartOfAccountIdCostOfSale")]
        public virtual ChartOfAccount ChartOfAccountCostOfSale { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using required tag for all chartOfAccounts that's why it was  througing exception.

Answer (score 0):

you should set  "**WillCascadeOnDelete = False**" by fluentApi, Like This :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
         modelBuilder.Entity<Paper>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.ChartOfAccountSale )
            //.WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ChartOfAccountIdSale)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Paper>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.ChartOfAccountInventory )
            //.WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ChartOfAccountIdInventory )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Paper>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.ChartOfAccountCostOfSale )
            //.WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ChartOfAccountIdCostOfSale )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

}